# Архивация при помощи GZip

Tags: c#

Мне задали задачку написать архиватор, который может эффективно работать в многопроцессорной среде, при этом он должен обрабатывать, файлы размер которых превышает обьем доступной оперативной памяти (без пула потоков и BackgroundWorker).

У меня возник вопрос: хватит ли для этой задачи обычных функций для работы с потоками или, например, лучше использовать tpl?

Мне подсказали, что лучше всего делить поток входящих данных на равные части и запускать потоки для сжатия каждой из частей, а затем соединять их в один поток. Только я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать. Если не трудно можете скинуть ссылки на приложение/статьи где это все освещено.

Так же я не совсем понимаю как решить вопрос с зависимостью архивации больший файлов от оперативной памяти.

Comment: `У меня возник вопрос: хватит ли для этой задачи обычных функций для работы с потоками или, например, лучше использовать tpl? `

Вопрос скорее наоборот должен быть :) TPL это для удобства обёртка.

По второй части можете попробовать Producer/Consumer использовать (на сайте в разделе `Исследования` посмотрите)

От количества памяти и зависит размер вашей "равной" части. То есть, делите файл на такие части, чтобы оперативной памяти хватало (ну и соответсвенно должно быть ограничение на количество одновременно обрабатываемых частей)

Comment: 1. Вы не с того начинаете. Начните с алгоритма, постарайтесь, чтобы он был параллелизируем. Это самое сложное. Разогнать подзадачи по потокам — самое простое дело, если алгоритм упаковки есть.
2. «Обычные» функции работы с потоками гораздо менее удобны, чем TPL. Откуда взялось требование «без пула потоков и BackgroundWorker», не понимаю. Как именно реализована многопоточность, не должно быть частью ТЗ.
3. Проблема с зависимостью от оперативки решается просто: вы читаете кусок исходного файла, архивируете, записываете заархивированный кусок в другой файл, и освобождаете память. И т. д.

Comment: @Veikedo, спасибо за ответ.
@VladD, если вы помните я тут спрашивал недавно про XML, так это практически то же самое, т.е задача от работодателя. [Нашел вполне удачный пример](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49264/Parallel-fast-compression-unleashing-the-power-of). [И еще один.](http://pragmaticcoding.com/index.php/howto-using-tpl-dataflow-for-multithreaded-file-compression/) Осталось разобраться, благо дали одну неделю.

Comment: @Sier: ого, ну у вас и работодатель. Требуйте позицию senior'а немедленно.

Comment: @VladD, это задача на позицию джуниора )

Comment: @Sier: В таком случае вас дурят. Уходите из этой конторы. (Разве что это гугл.)

Comment: @VladD, я же только устраиваюсь ) да и [компания](http://www.veeam.com/) вроде бы достаточно серьезная

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), места в комментариях не хватило, поэтому оставлю как ответ. Возможно у меня появятся вопросы по этой же теме, поэтому закрывать данный топик пока не хотелось бы. Я только устраиваюсь, да и [компания](http://www.veeam.com/) достаточно серьезная, на первый взгляд. Возможно, исходя из первого моего поста вы оценили сложность задачи, видимо я сам немного прикукрасил, но дело в том, что они хотят только многопоточность, GZip сжатие и все. Про деление потока данных на блоки я уже сам начал рассуждать, т.к если сделать без этого, то выполнение данной задачи достаточно тривиально. Просто хотелось выделиться и пойти вот на такие сложности думаю это будет хорошим плюсом. Да и работка очень нужна на данный момент.

UPD 1:
Тогда как мне поступить, сразу писать эти блоки в файл ? Просто других вариантов у меня пока просто нет. Расширение заранее известно, а расположение думаю можно определить по расположению файла, который нужно сжать.

UPD 2:
Хорошо, сегодня попробую сделать поочерендную упаковку блоков. Я никак не могу разобрать исходники [этого](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49264/Parallel-fast-compression-unleashing-the-power-of) проекта, тяжеловато, оставили бы хотя бы комментарии к методам (

UPD 3: 
Написал вроде бы, но вот только не понимаю как запустить задачу в цикле на сжатие блока. [Вот тут код](http://pastebin.com/86VxiSdf). Я уже окончательно запутался. И да, нужно освобождать память после того как произошло сжатие блока ? Нужно переписать метод CompressChunk, а то наворотил я что то там не то...

UPD 4:
В общем силы мои иссякли и надежда закончить все в срок тоже. Отправил письмо и все что смог написать. [[[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), спасибо огромное за помощь и объяснения, а то я так бы и топтался на месте. Так же спасибо [[@Veiked](/users/6921/veikedo)](/users/6921/veikedo). Доделаю это дело как нибудь позже.

Comment: Не совсем понял вашего вопроса ? Вы про System.IO.Compression.GzipStream или подключение сторонней библиотеки ? В моем случае нужно использовать первый вариант. Но вот блочное оно или нет я не нарыл. В спецификации тоже не увидел, либо неправильно смотрел.

Comment: @VladD, вот, можете взглянуть на [код](http://pastebin.com/GCWxQ4ky) ? Нужно добавить исключения и регулярки для обработки входящих запросов. Меня смущает то, что я никак не могу сделать так, чтобы на входе при распаковке имя указывалось один раз, тут же при копировании memory stream в file stream нужно указывать имя ручками, что неправильно. Может просто не возвращать memory stream а делать сразу все в этом же методе ? хм..

Comment: @VladD, 
1) В задании говорят что нужно запускать методы с помощью командной строки, т.е compress [имя файла][расширение архива]
2) в основе gzip лежит алгоритм deflate (комбинация алгоритмов LZ77 и Хоффмана), а в нем насколько я понял как раз и используется разбиение потока данных на блоки. Поэтому сделал без этого, но думаю к вечеру попробую сделать и с разделением на блоки.
3) На счет всего остального понял. Исправлюсь.
Можете поделиться ссылочкой на статью где показывают на примере как справиться с зависимостью от оперативной памяти ? Если не сложно )

Comment: @Sier: 1) А, параметеры комстроки! Ну это самая маленькая проблема. Регулярки, кстати, не нужны.

3) Ну, например, напишите собственную реализацию Stream'а, почти как FileStream, которая будет данные не держать в памяти, а писать в файл, начиная с заданного смещения (важно!). Ну или в качестве временного неэффективного решения распакуйте часть в MemoryStream, и по окончанию сбросьте его в файл и освободите память (очень хорошо ляжет на async/await). Ссылки не знаю, сорри.

Comment: @VladD, Так, я примерно сообразил как сделать. Но, вот только вопрос, после того, как я делю поток данных на блоки и сжимаю их, мне их сразу же записывать в файл ? Просто, насколько я понял, они, после сжатия, еще должны соединяться воедино и уже только потом записываться в файл. Если, же они должны будут соединяться воедино перед записью, то, я не понимаю как это реализовать. При этом они должны где то храниться, самый оптимальный вариант, который пришел в голову, это хранить сжатые блоки в промежуточном файле, т.к если хранить их List, то выйдет слишком "памятезатратно". Я немного растерян.

Comment: @Sier: Хм. Это легко для распаковки: распаковали кусок, и сразу можно писать его в файл (если знаете, где он лежит). А вот для запаковки так просто не получится, так как (1) вы не знаете, сколько занимают предыдущие куски, и (2) вы не знаете формат файла: верно ли, что запаковать два куска и записать их друг за другом это всё равно что запаковать один большой кусок, состоящий из двух?

Comment: @Sier: ну, а вы уже ответили себе на вопрос (2)? Боюсь, что дописать один кусок к другому просто так не получится, как не получится объединить функциональность Word'а и Excel'я, если просто дописать один excel.exe в хвост word.exe. Попробуйте запаковать два куска данных поочерёдно, и потом сложить их вместе. Если получится, можно думать о параллелизации. Если нет, боюсь, вам придётся копаться в формате сжатого файла руками.

Comment: @Sier: Нет-нет, вы неправильно походите. Вы не должны в цикле читать, каждое задание должно самостоятельно прочитать нужный кусок.

Но вы пока занимаетесь относительно несложными техническими проблемами, хотя даже не приступили к главной сложности. Допустим даже, что у вас есть запакованные куски; **как** вы собираетесь склеить из них один валидный `.gz`-файл? Вы уверены, что простое приписывание в конец сработает? Прежде чем идти дальше, проясните для себя этот вопрос. Без этого всё остальное бессмысленно. Понимаете?