# Как добавить информацию в начало сжатого файла ?

Tags: c#

[В продолжение темы про архивацию.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/334088/c-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-gzip)
Я решил вопрос с параллельным сжатием и записью блоков в файл. Но у меня появился вопрос, т.к блоки записываются непоследовательно, то для параллельной декомпрессии блоков мне нужно знать смещение и длину, но я подумал что лучше брать ID блока и его длину для записи. Я никак не могу понять, как записать эту информацию в сжатый файл и прочитать ?

Comment: 1. Как обычно. Записываете скомпирессированные куски во временный файл, создаёте файл с «оглавлением», дописываете временный файл в хвост.
2. А как gzip будет распаковывать? Или распаковка должна быть только вашей утилитой?

Comment: @VladD, сейчас файл можно успешно разархивировать например 7ZIP архиватором. Распаковка должна быть и в моей утилите. Не совсем понял первый вопрос.

Comment: @Sier: А, ну если формат разрешает куски один за другим, то вам просто надо распарсить формат и найти длину каждого куска.

P. S.: А распаковывает правильно? Длина файла после распаковки не изменяется?

Comment: @VladD, да, распаковывает нормально, тестировал несколько раз как на маленьких так и на больших файлах. Размеры совпадают.